# how to change the file download location of firefox using javascript

Tags: firefox, javascript

i need to export some files on local machine . so i need to choose some location to save files.
Instead of that i need to exported file in certain location in my local machine automatically.
Is it possible in firefox to change the download location using javascript?

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/foo/bar"); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
```

like this in javascript for firefox. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking if its possible to change the client's download location through JavaScript.  I am glade to report that JavaScript does not have this capability otherwise we would all be in trouble.